# Can we remove unwanted delimiters from java

Tags: java, date

I wanted that the program takes input removes the delimiters from that String then add it back then I can later parse it to a `LocalDate` object but I am not able to do the needful.

```
Scanner darshit = new Scanner(System.in);
String oo = "";
System.out.println("Enter your DOB: ");
String dob = darshit.next();
String[] words = dob.split("\\D");
for (int i = 0; i > words.length; i++) {
    oo = oo + words[i];
}
System.out.println(oo);
```

After entering the DOB as 25-06-2008, for example, the output should be 25062008 or 2662008 but instead of this, I get a blank line!

Comment: In the first place, the loop condition is wrong: It shoud be `i < words.length`.

Comment: Use a StringBuilder instead of +

Comment: What about just using String.replace()?  oo = dob.replace("-", "") will remove the dashes from the string.

Comment: Shouldn't it be nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: Have you created *another* account?

Comment: bschellekens it will not work because i want to remove every type of delimiters such as / _ etc . So ```String.replace()``` wont work

Comment: Andy turner Nooooo

Comment: Abishek Stephen No , because I only want the first word , which can be fulfilled by ```next()```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the input string to `LocalDate` and then format the `LocalDate` into a String of the desired format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner darshit = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your DOB: ");
        String dob = darshit.next();
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd[-][/]MM[-][/]uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dob, dtfInput);
        // Output in the default format i.e. LocalDate#toString implementation
        // System.out.println(date);

        // Output in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

Notice the optional patterns in the square bracket which one of the great things about `DateTimeFormatter`.

**A sample run:**

```
Enter your DOB: 25-06-2008
25062008
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter your DOB: 25/06/2008
25062008
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I can't use ```DateTimeFormatter``` because It is not fixed the the input from which I want to remove delimiters is dd-MM-uuuu , it can also be dd/MM/uuuu . So is there something for this ?

Comment: @Darshitff - In that case, you should use `dd[-][/]MM[-][/]uuuu` as the pattern which will allow you to input 25-06-2008 or 25/06/2008. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

### String.replaceAll() and DateTimeFormatter

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[-]d-M-u[-]", Locale.ROOT);
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.ROOT);

public static void parseAndFormat(String input) {
    String adapted = input.replaceAll("\\W+", "-");
    System.out.println("Adapted input string: " + adapted);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(adapted, DATE_PARSER);
    String formatted = date.format(DATE_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println("Formatted:            " + formatted);
}
```

The above method parses your string:

```
    parseAndFormat("25-06-2008");
```

Output:

> ```
> Adapted input string: 25-06-2008
> Formatted:            25-06-2008
> ```

It’s very tolerant to which delimiters the users decides to use between the numbers, and also before or after them if any:

```
    parseAndFormat("$5///7  2008 ?");
```

> ```
> Adapted input string: -5-7-2008-
> Formatted:            05-07-2008
> ```

How it works: `input.replaceAll("\\W+", "-")` substitutes any run of non-word characters — everything but letters a through z and digits 0 through 9 — with a single hyphen. No one is interested in seeing the adapted input string, I am only printing it for you to understand the process better. The formatter I use for parsing accepts an optional hyphen first and last. The square brackets in the format pattern denote optional parts. It also accepts day and month in 1 or 2 digits and year in up to 9 digits. I use a separate formatter for formatting so I can control that day and month come in 2 digits and there are no hyphens before nor after.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use Java Streams with the Collectors joining call ?

```
String value = Arrays.asList(dob.split("\\D")).stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: While string bashing kind of works, it is not the best way.  Consider the case where the user enter their DOB as 2008-05-07.  Or 123456789.

Answer (score -1):

I myself found the solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your DOB: ");
    String dateOfBirth = scanner.next();
    String dateOfBirth1 = dateOfBirth.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String[] dateOfBirthArray = dateOfBirth1.split("[\\s\\-\\.\\'\\?\\,\\_\\@]+");
      int[] dateOfBirthArray1 = new int[dateOfBirthArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < dateOfBirthArray.length; i++){
        dateOfBirthArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(dateOfBirthArray[i]);
      }
      int dayDateOfBirth = dateOfBirthArray1[0] , monthDateOfBirth = dateOfBirthArray1[1];
      int yearDateOfBirth = dateOfBirthArray1[2];
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
      LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(yearDateOfBirth, monthDateOfBirth, dayDateOfBirth);
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
      String birthday1 = birthday.format(formatter);
  }
}
```

According to me it is the easiest way and the public editors can edit the post for making it more clear

Comment: It’s a *very* complicated way.  Please use a `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Comment: That is the best way lol , Let me try ```DateTimeFormatter```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry but relying on other people to edit your answer into good shape is ... not on.  Especially since the the approach your code takes is overly complicated.